# Office add-ins: Creating word document or text file in Excel Add-ins

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

Is it possible to create a .docx or .txt file from an Excel Add-In?

My use case is to open an Excel file, open the Add-In and in the Add-In perform some task and then store the output in a word document or text file.
The .docx/.txt file should get downloaded.

I have tried to create a .docx or .txt file, but it is working only in the browser and not in the excel file.

Comment: Which library do you call? Does it support IE11 and Edge?  Currently some system still run IE11 and some run in Chrome Edge. So need to ensure the js library can support the browser you are hitting.

Comment: In edge when I am opening office.com and trying to download(the .docx file that I have created) it is getting downloaded. but if I am opening the excel sheet and then trying to hit the download(this is not open in browser) that time nothing is happening.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? What code is working in a browser and not in Excel?